# Autofac RegisterInstance vs SingleInstance

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

```
IProductRepositoryProxy ProductDataServiceProviderInstance = new ServiceProductDataProvider();
builder.RegisterInstance(ProductDataServiceProviderInstance).As<IProductRepositoryProxy>();
```

**VS**

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceProductDataProvider>().As<IProductRepositoryProxy>().InstancePerRequest();
```

I saw this code from an ex-employee here and wonder if the guy wanted to register a .SingleInstance() behavior.

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceProductDataProvider>().As<IProductRepositoryProxy>().SingleInstance();
```

Is the manual newing-up of the ServiceProductDataProvider with RegisterInstance not the same as the Register .SingleInstance() ??

Answer (score 93, accepted):

> Is the manual newing-up of the ServiceProductDataProvider with RegisterInstance not the same as the Register .SingleInstance() ??

The `RegisterInstance` allows you to register a single instance in *AutoFac*.

The difference between `RegisterInstance` and `RegisterType` + `SingleInstance` methods is that the `RegisterInstance` method allows you to register an instance not built by *Autofac*.

But both solution will result in registering a singleton in *Autofac*.

By the way, both registration are equivalent in the following code sample

```
var instance = GetInstanceFromSomewhere(); 

builder.RegisterInstance<IService>(instance); 
builder.Register(c => instance).As<IService>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Would this code be also the same and equivalent to your TWO .Register calls above? => builder.RegisterType<ServiceProductDataProvider>().As<IProductRepositoryProxy>().SingleInstance(); I use the RegisterType which you did not mention.

Comment: @Elisa not strictly equivalent. With the `RegisterType` + `SingleInstance` solution, you register a singleton in *Autofac* (like the other solution) but you don't have to provide the instance, *Autofac* will build it the first time is required whereas for the `RegisterInstance` *Autofac* don't create the instance and it has to be created during the registration process

Comment: ok but in the end its technically the same a Singleton instance shared the whole application lifecycle until IIS goes down...

Comment: @Elisa. Yes. As far as the container is live, the instance will be shared

Comment: Its a single instance its not a singleton. A Singleton prohibits creating a new instance of that component (e.g. with a private constructor)